# Is there a way to load different views for one route depending on user role?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

Is there some implementation if I want to use the main page path '/' for different views depending on roles? Like if you are an authorized user you will see the `MainAuth`, if you are a guest you will see the `MainGuest`? Here is some code that would help me to explain.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'main_auth',
    component: MainAuth,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'main_guest',
    component: MainGuest,
    meta: {
      requiresGuest: true
    }
  }
]
```

For this example, it just loads the first path I declared whatever I am a guest or user.  To be more specific, I have a login/register module on the main path '/' and I want to load an authorized user page on the same path '/' after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use only one path, you could use a basic route and do the work in the component itself.  The route:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'main',
    component: Main,
  }
]
```

`Main` view component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Auth v-if="!loggedIn" />
    <MainContent v-else />
  </div>
</template>
```

`Auth` component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Login v-if="showLogin" />
    <Register v-else />
  </div>
</template>
```

With this, you check if the user is logged in from the `Main` view component and show either the `Auth` component or the main content.

Then, in the `Auth` component, you use a toggle that allows the user to switch between a `Login` and `Register` component.

Comment: Looks like working solution, thanks, I will check it out soon.
Is it a bad practice to do this instead of routing auth modules and a user page to different routes?

Comment: You're welcome.  I think it's just a matter of preference.  The main effect is probably that you can't link directly to the login or register view because they don't have their own route.

Answer (score 6):

Here are 3 options:

**1. Simple Computed View**

To allow a single route to display any number of conditional views, use a computed component.

Register views:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

import ViewDefault from '/views/Default.vue'
Vue.component('view-default', ViewDefault )

import ViewAuth from '/views/Auth.vue'
Vue.component('view-auth', ViewAuth )

import ViewGuest from '/views/Guest.vue'
Vue.component('view-guest', ViewGuest)
```

Route:

```
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'index',
    component: ViewDefault
  },
```

View `Default.vue`

```js
<template>
  <component :is="view"></component>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  name: 'view-default',

  computed: {

   view() {
     return this.isAuthenticated ? 'view-auth' : 'view-guest'
   }  

  }

}

</script>
```

You will be able to create as many conditional checks you want in `view()`.

---

**2. Conditional Named Views ( Concept not tried )**

I would consider experimenting with the use of named views, I believe you could double view many paths with user and guest versions, not something I tried yet:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html

```js
<template>

  <div>

    <template v-if="isAuthenticated">
      <router-view name="authed"/>
    </template>
  
    <template v-else>
      <router-view/>
    </template>

  </div>

</template>
```

`Router`

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: MainGuest,
        authed: MainAuth,
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

---

**3. Computed Layouts**

However ... I personally use I/O blocking layouts, computed `layout`.

I check various application states that control what layouts are displayed depending on the conditions before a final layout is computed that would contain `<router-view>`.

I let the router paths specify custom layouts via `meta` data, set alternate layout else falls back to default layout.

`Router`

```js
  {
    name: 'index',
    path: '/',
    meta: {
      title: 'Welcome',
      guard: 'auth'
    },
    component: import('@/views/welcome')
  },

  {
    name: 'settings',
    path: '/settings',
    meta: {
      title: 'Account Settings',
      layout: 'settings',
      guard: 'auth'
    },
    component:  import('@/views/account-settings')
  }
```

`App.vue`

```js
<template>

  <div id="app" v-cloak :class="$root.layout">

    <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
      <component :is="$root.layout"/>
    </transition>

  </div>

</template>
```

`main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import '@/views/layouts'
import App from './App'


// Use Vuex to store states, `axios` calls and response `interceptors` are used to `commit` computed mapped state conditions globally.

import { mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

Vue.mixin({

  computed: {

    ...mapState(['user', 'isAuthenticating', 'isOffline']),

    ...mapGetters(['isAuthenticated']),

  }

})

new Vue({

  el: '#app'
  render: h => h(App),
  store,
  router,

  computed: {

    layout () { // could move this to vuex and access via mapGetters...

      if (this.isOffline) {
        return 'layout-offline'
      }

      if (this.isAuthenticating) {
        return 'layout-authenticating'
      }

      if (this.$route.meta.hasOwnProperty('guard')) {

        if(this.$route.meta.guard === 'auth' && !this.isAuthenticated) {
          return 'layout-login'
        }

      }

      // If current route has a preferred layout use it else fallback to `layout-default`
      let layout = this.$route.meta.layout || 'default'

      return `layout-${layout}`
    }

  },

})
```

`views/layouts/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import LayoutOffline from './layout-offline')
import LayoutAuthenticating from './layout-authenticating')
import LayoutLogin from './layout-login')

import LayoutDefault from './layout-default')
import LayoutSettings from './layout-settings')

Vue.component('layout-offline', LayoutOffline)
Vue.component('layout-authenticating', LayoutAuthenticating)
Vue.component('layout-login', LayoutLogin)

Vue.component('layout-default', LayoutDefault)
Vue.component('layout-settings', Layoutsettings)
```

Only `layout-default` or any router path specifying a custom layout should contain `<router-view>` along with header, footer, sidebar etc...

You could mix this up with name views, different computed layouts could display a different named `router-view` for the same `path`.

Comment: I tried the second option, and can confirm it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the user to another route using the *beforeEach* method.

Example :

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Determine if the route requires Authentication
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth);
  const user = auth.getUser();

  // If it does and they are not logged in, send the user to "/login"
  if (requiresAuth && !user) {
    next("/login");
  } else {
    // Else let them go to their next destination
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it works, but it's not that I am actually talking about. I have login/register on the main page '/', and I want to load an authorized user page on the same path '/'. So, I need like skip the route for a user if I am a guest and load view for my role, and vice versa.

Comment: I don't know that it is possible to declare two identical routes, another way of achieving this would be to use props: isAuthorized in one route, and then use this prop value for conditional rendering (v-if, v-show)

Comment: That is actually what this answer showed you to do:  skip the route (i.e. redirect) if it's a guest.  This code: `next("/login")` is a redirect.

Comment: @Dan, no, I don't need a redirect. I have login/register view on the main path '/' and I want to show authorized user page view on the same main path '/' after sing in. So I need like "redirect" to '/', but it gives just the first main path declared in the router anyway.